# Using Registry and data providers

Tags: magento2.2, registry

I want to use Registry class (vendor/magento/framework/Registry.php)
But above file mentioned something like this

> It's usage should be avoid. Use service classes or data providers
>   instead.

Can you please anyone provide the best method to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please  checkout the article https://www.atwix.com/development/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Comment: https://www.atwix.com/development/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/